# Peer discovery with peerjs

Tags: webrtc, peerjs

I run ExpressPeerServer

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var ExpressPeerServer = require('peer').ExpressPeerServer;

app.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    console.log("get /")
    res.send(connected);
});

var server = app.listen(9000);
var options = {
    debug: true,
    allow_discovery: true
};

var connected = [];


peerServer = ExpressPeerServer(server, options)
app.use('/bwallet', peerServer);

peerServer.on('connection', function(id) {
    var idx = connected.indexOf(id); // only add id if it's not in the list yet
    if (idx === -1) {connected.push(id);}
    console.log(connected);
});
peerServer.on('disconnect', function (id) {
    var idx = connected.indexOf(id); // only attempt to remove id if it's in the list
    if (idx !== -1) {connected.splice(idx, 1);}
    console.log(connected);
});
server.on('disconnect', function(id) {
    console.log(id + " disconnect")
});
```

Is there an event in client side where peer can listen to know the subscribe to other connected peers (I know I can implement socket.io but prefer that the signaling server will handle it. )?
I don't want to get '/' on interval for performance issues.
peer.listAllPeers() returns undefined as well.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want a client-side event (without implementing your own Socket.io solution) to know when another peer is connected (so that the client may connect to it).

One solution could be to create and connect a master peer on server start with a fixed peer-id (say 'MASTER'). Now all the clients connect to MASTER. MASTER broadcasts the peer-id to all connected peers (clients) whenever a new peer connects.

The clients should listen to 'data' event from the MASTER peer.

Comment: I've PR peerjs and peerjs express server to add support for peer discovery.